# Is there an API call that can be used to check the health of the Here API?

Tags: rest, here-api, kubernetes-health-check

I'm integrating the usage of the Here API in a service that I'm creating which is hosted on a kubernetes cluster.

I typically have health checks for my services.  For example, checking if a database is up and running.

Is there any API call for the Here API that can be used as a health check?
Keep in mind, it should be a call that wouldn't count towards the request limits for cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you can find it here: https://status.here.com/status?id=services_status_api. Let me know if this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I don't know why I couldn't find that.  Another question for you.  It seems to indicate that a 200 will always be returned.  Is that correct?  So I need to check on the return data and can't rely on the returned status code.

Comment: I haven't used this API myself so if the docs say this, then yes. If we are talking about a "status" API, to me it makes sense to return good status codes. The API itself (the status one) isn't erroring when it reports an error on some other service.